# Launching multiple mapreduce jobs using same mapreduce code/jar

Tags: hadoop

I am running a mapreduce job using Table MapReduce Util which takes the hbase table data(1 million rows) as input,In mapper I am evaluating a particular set of expressions for every row input from hbase table and it was getting completed less time as long as expressions to be evaluated for a particular row were around 10 to 20.

But as the number of expressions have increased to 100(to be calculated for every row in hbase table) my mapreduce job is taking so much time so i thought of using the same job(same mapreduce jar) in parallel for 10 times with 10 expressions each so that if all the jobs run in parallel i can achieve the output faster. I tried to launch 10 jobs in parallel using a shell script but initially 2 jobs are getting completed in parallel and then only it's launching other two jobs and so on...As far as my understanding this jar file is able to launch only 2 parallel jobs at a time and it's only allowing the other jobs to access it only when the current running jobs gets completed.

so is there any other way to launch all the jobs in parallel using the same map reduce jar file...?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inside the job that void to be executed more than 2 times in parallel. MapReduce and HBase support it.

IMO, the problem is with your nodes' resources. If there is not enough slots available to execute the next tasks, then your jobs are been queued until the resources have been released. Working more as sequential than in parallel.

You can add more nodes (and distribute the data to the new nodes to be functional) or tune the resources configuration (memory used by task, scheduler, vCores, etc) to see if that resolve your problem.